# Similarity for arrays of parts of speech

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, knn

K-nearest neighbor and natural language processing: How do you test the distance between arrays of parts of speech? eg

('verb','adverb','noun')  and ('adjective','adverb','pronoun')?

A better phrased question would be how do you tell the similarity between the two in the context that they are parts of speech and not just strings?

Answer (score 2):

As a general approach, you can use the [cosine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between POS vectors as a measure of their similarity. Alternative approach would be using the [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between the two vectors.

There are plenty of other distance functions between vectors. But it really depends on what you want to do and what does your data look like. You should answer questions like does the position matter? How much similarity would you give to these vectors? ('noun', 'verb') and ('verb', 'noun')? Is the distance between ('adverb') and ('adjective') less than distance between ('adverb') and ('noun')? and so on.